# Get corners of rectangle from black and white image

Tags: python, opencv

Let's say that we have the following black and white image (`image.png`):

[image]

We load the image using `OpenCV2` with the following code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
```

How can we detect the corners of all white rectangles in an image? We can assume that all rectangles are **parallel** to the corners of the image.

Result in this case should be in the following form (`res[0]` is left rectangle and `res[1]` is right rectangle):

```
res = [
    [
        (20, 30), # upper left
        (40, 30), # upper right
        (20, 80), # bottom left
        (40, 80)  # bottom right
    ],
    [
        (100, 20), # upper left
        (140, 20), # upper right
        (100, 70), # bottom left
        (140, 70)  # bottom right
    ]
]
```

Comment: I'll just offer a hint in case this is homework. Assuming I'm understanding what you're asking, think about the 8 neighbors of each pixel (except for those on the edge of the image, which of course have fewer neighbors). The status of the neighbors of a white pixel tells you where that pixel lies in the rectangle with respect to the rectangle features (edges, corners, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities:

- the *"Harris Corner Detector"* is good at finding corners - see [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html)
- you can use OpenCV's [findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)
- you could use *"Hit-or-Miss"* [morphology](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#hitmiss) to look for corners
- you could convolve the image with a kernel and look for specific outputs

So, looking at the last option, if we slide a 2x2 pixel kernel over the image and multiply each of the elements underneath the kernel by 1 and add them all together, and then find all the pixels where that total comes to 255, that will be a 2x2 square where exactly one pixel is white - and that is a corner:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image as greyscale
im = cv2.imread('tZHHE.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Make a 2x2 kernel of ones
kernel = np.ones((2,2), dtype=np.uint8)

# Convolve the image with the kernel
res = cv2.filter2D(im.astype(np.int16), -1, kernel)

# Get coordinates of points where the sum of the 2x2 window comes to 255
corners = np.where(res==255)
```

**Sample Output**

```
(array([101, 101, 118, 118, 166, 166, 174, 174]),
 array([274, 307, 117, 134, 274, 307, 117, 134]))
```

---

Looking at the *"Hit-or-Miss"* morphology method, I will do it with **ImageMagick** straight in the Terminal, but you can equally do it with other Python libraries:

```
magick tZHHE.png -alpha off -morphology HMT Corners result.png
```

As always, I am indebted to Anthony Thyssen for his **ImageMagick** examples as linked above. We are looking for these specific shapes with the *"Hit-or-Miss"* morphology:

[image]

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, OpenCV, image processing, convolution, corner detect, corner detector, corner detection, ImageMagick Hit-or-Miss morphology.

Answer (score 1):

This works for any number of rectangles:[image]

```
import cv2 as cv
import pprint as pprint

img = cv.imread("tZHHE.png") # read image
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # make grayscale image

cv.imshow("Our initial image",img) # show our original image 

corners = cv.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,2000,0.01,5) # find our corners, 2000 is the number of corners we can detect, 5 is the distance between corners 

xylist = [] #put all of our xy coords in here 

for corn in corners: # extract our corners and put them in xylist
    x,y = corn[0]
    xylist.append((x,y))
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    cv.rectangle(img, (x-2,y-2), (x+2,y+2), (100,100,0),-1) # now mark where our corners are on our original image
            
res = [[] for i in range(int(len(xylist)/4))] # generate i nested lists for our rectangles
        
for index, item in enumerate(xylist): # format coordinates as you want them
   res[index % int(len(xylist)/4)].append(item)
        
print("\n"+"found ",int(len(xylist)/4) ,"rectangles\n") # how many rectangles did we have?       
print(res)
cv.imshow("Corners?", img) # show our new image with rectangle corners marked
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly even with very complex images, just by tweaking the third parameter in goodFeaturesToTrack.

Answer (score 1):

### Try findContours()

I suggest you to try [findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) with its companion [boundingRect()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7).

Here is how you can make it work.

Load the image in grayscale, then pass it to the function findContours().

```
img = cv2.imread('tZHHe.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Getting the bounding box from contours, it returns `x, y` coordinates of the top left corner and `w, h` the width and height of the box:

```
[cv2.boundingRect(contour) for contour in contours]
#=> [(117, 118, 17, 56), (274, 101, 33, 65)]
```

---

### View in action

Try this maybe in a Jupyter Notebook to see a kind of animation:

```
def corners_from_bounding_rect(bounding_rect):
    x, y, w, h = bounding_rect
    points = {'top_left': (x, y), 'top_right':(x+w, y), 'bottom-left': (x, y+h), 'bottom-rigth':(x+w, y+h)}
    return points
```

Retrieve the points from contours using the method defined:

```
corner_groups = [corners_from_bounding_rect(cv2.boundingRect(cnt)) for cnt in contours]

# [{'top_left': (117, 118),
#   'top_right': (134, 118),
#   'bottom-left': (117, 174),
#   'bottom-rigth': (134, 174)},
#  {'top_left': (274, 101),
#   'top_right': (307, 101),
#   'bottom-left': (274, 166),
#   'bottom-rigth': (307, 166)}]
```

Then plot the sequence:

```
pinned_img = img.copy()

for n, corners in enumerate(corner_groups):
    for name, point in corners.items():
        cv2.circle(pinned_img, point, 10, 255)
        plt.title(f'{n}-{name}')
        plt.imshow(pinned_img)
        plt.show()
```

The first image from the squence:

[image: image output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
[image]

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread('tZHHE.png') # Read my Image
imgContours=img.copy() # Copy my Image for Contours
imgCanny=cv2.Canny(imgContours,10,50)  # Image to Edges

contours,hierarchy =cv2.findContours(imgCanny,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
rectangles=[]
for cont in reversed(contours):
    area=cv2.contourArea(cont)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    rectangles.append([[x,y],[x+w,y],[x+w,y+h],[x,y+h]])
    cv2.imshow("con", imgContours)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

print(rectangles)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

left to right rectangles

```
Output:
[[[273, 100], [307, 100], [307, 166], [273, 166]], [[116, 117], [134, 117], [134, 174], [116, 174]]]
```